# Band SDK:MissingManifestResourceException when calling TileManager.AddTileAsync(

Tags: microsoft-band

Hi I've got a problem with a MissingManifestResourceException that I found a similar post on the MSDN forums whereby they were advised to post here which the OP didn't. I've therefore re-posted it here because the OP explains the problem far more eloquently than I am able to...

[Original Post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/26152266-c96f-4dbe-8315-31b86eedf129/microsoft-band-development?forum=Offtopic)

Hi,

don't know if it's the right forum.

I've tried creating a simple test tile on the MS Band and I'm becoming crazy. I'm developing using Windows 10 10074 and VS 2015 CTP.

First of all, when an Exception is thrown you always get a misleading `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` hiding your actual exception (from what is seems is unable to find a localized resource content). By checking the stack trace you get your actual exception at the second position from the top.

Second, when I create a simple tile with no layouts or anything else, everything goes well. But as soon as I add something as simple as this:

```
var controlsPageLayout = new PageLayout(new FilledPanel() { Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102) });

tile.PageLayouts.Add(controlsPageLayout);
```

I get both a `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` and a `Microsoft.Band.BandIOException`. Here's the stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.DynamicPageLayoutSetLayout(Guid appId, UInt32 layoutIndex, PageLayout layout)
at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.AddTileOutsideSync(BandTile tile)
at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.<>c__DisplayClass9b.<AddTile>b__9a()
at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.RunUsingSynchronizedFirmwareUI(Action insideSync, Action afterSync)
at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.AddTile(BandTile tile, Guid applicationId, IReadOnlyList`1 installedTiles)
at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.<>c__DisplayClass6f.<<AddTileAsync>b__6c>d__71.MoveNext()
```

Do you know what's the possible cause for these issues? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the trace for the first exception? I think I know what the problem is and I'm working on a sample to replicate the problem and a solution:)

Comment: Hi Iris, thanks for the help. As you can see below I'm pretty sure its something do with running it in 2015 RC.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think the problem is somehow related to Visual Studio 2015 RC. I re-installed 2013 Update 4 (on windows TP 10074)  and the problem no longer occurs.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Using VS 2015 CTP6 was working nice. Now I have VS2015RC and got this exception.

A quick and dirty fix : just put the AddTileAsync around a try/catch!
I did this after seeing that even if it throws exception the tile is on my band and the exception looks to be when getting localized status for the add command (my laptop is set in french locals). So bypass the exception and try to run the .SetPagesAsync : works like a charm...
Here is my code :

```
await bandClient.TileManager.RemoveTileAsync(myTile.TileId);
try
{
    await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(myTile);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AddTileOk");
}
catch (BandIOException bandex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"ex:{bandex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}InnerException : {bandex.InnerException}");
    if (bandex.Message != "Exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' was thrown.")
        throw;
}
await bandClient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(myTile.TileId, page);
```

For info, here is the InnerException:

> {System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException:
>   Exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException'
>   was thrown.    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String
>   name, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   Microsoft.Band.BandResources.get_CommandStatusError()    at
>   Microsoft.Band.BandClient.CheckStatus(CargoStatus status,
>   CommandStatusHandling statusHandling)    at
>   Microsoft.Band.BandClient.DynamicPageLayoutSetLayout(Guid appId,
>   UInt32 layoutIndex, PageLayout layout)}
>       [System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException]: {System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Exception of type
>   'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' was thrown.    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at Microsoft.Band.BandResources.get_CommandStatusError()
>   at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.CheckStatus(CargoStatus status,
>   CommandStatusHandling statusHandling)    at
>   Microsoft.Band.BandClient.DynamicPageLayoutSetLayout(Guid appId,
>   UInt32 layoutIndex, PageLayout layout)}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HelpLink: null
>       HResult: -2146233038
>       InnerException: null
>       Message: "Exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' was thrown."
>       Source: "mscorlib"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo
>   culture)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Band.BandResources.get_CommandStatusError()\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Band.BandClient.CheckStatus(CargoStatus status,
>   CommandStatusHandling statusHandling)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Band.BandClient.DynamicPageLayoutSetLayout(Guid appId,
>   UInt32 layoutIndex, PageLayout layout)

Hope this helps!